# What's the easiest way to find the coordinates of an object in a image?

Tags: image, api, object, coordinates, analysis

Imagine having an image of circles of different colors on a background of one color. What would be the easiest way to find the coordinates of the circles' centers (of course *programmatically*)?

Comment: Do the circles overlap each other? Could they be concentric? Is your image JPEG or PNG or other? What OS do you use? What languages can you program in? What have you tried? Are the circles all just one single solid colour each? Are the circles fully contained in the image, or do some parts fall outside the background?

Comment: They don't overlap neither are concentric. The format of the images can be anything that helps the process. Both Windows and Linux. Only C and a tiny bit of Java, but I'm practicing Python right now. I'm a beginner working on a project that I came up with so except of Google-ing around I tried nothing. The circles are of solid colour and they never fall outside the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I felt like doing it in Python with OpenCV as well, using the same starting image as my other answer.

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('start.png')

# Convert to grayscale and threshold
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,1,255,0)

# Find contours, draw on image and save
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imwrite('result.png',im)

# Show user what we found
for cnt in contours:
   (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
   center = (int(x),int(y))
   radius = int(radius)
   print('Contour: centre {},{}, radius {}'.format(x,y,radius))
```

That gives this on the Terminal:

```
Contour: centre 400.0,200.0, radius 10
Contour: centre 500.0,200.0, radius 80
Contour: centre 200.0,150.0, radius 90
Contour: centre 50.0,50.0, radius 40
```

And this as the result image:

[image]

Comment: That's actually both very detailed and useful! I'm very grateful for your answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There's a very easy way with **ImageMagick** which is free and installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows - no programming required!

Let's start with this image:

[image]

Now you just run this in Terminal or Command Prompt:

```
magick input.png -define connected-components:verbose=true -connected-components 8 -auto-level output.png
```

**Output**

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 600x300+0+0 297.4,145.3 128391 srgb(0,0,0)          <--- black background
  2: 181x181+110+60 200.0,150.0 25741 srgb(0,0,255)      <--- blue circle
  3: 161x161+420+120 500.0,200.0 20353 srgb(255,0,255)   <--- magenta circle
  1: 81x81+10+10 50.0,50.0 5166 srgb(0,255,0)            <--- green circle
  4: 21x21+390+190 400.0,200.0 349 srgb(255,255,0).      <--- yellow circle
```

I added the comments above after `<---`.

Looking at the blue circle, you can see its colour is srgb(0,0,255) which is blue and it measures 181x181 pixels - so its radius is 90 pixels. The top-left corner of the containing rectangle is at `[110,60]` so the centre is at `[200,150]`, which matches the 200.00,150.00 given for the centroid.

Likewise, looking at the yellow circle, its colour is srgb(255,255,0) which is yellow. Its height and width are 21 pixels which means the radius is 10. The top-left corner of the containing square is at `[390,190]` which means the centre is at `[400,200]`, matching the centroid given as 400.0,200.0.

Comment: @fmw42 That's what I wrote, isn't it? That's what I meant anyway! Thank you.

Comment: I deleted my comment, Mark, when I saw you have asked the same thing. But for the OP's benefit, you could show how to extract only the colors and centroids excluding the black background as an addition to your answer.